# Show-Hide Tabs when Clicking options in DropDowns

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to make Show hide tabs on clicking on dropdown list. Well, i searched codepen and other places but couldn't find something anything similar.

But luckily, i find that in a marketing blog.

I'm sharing the link so that you can see what I'm talking about. Followed by I'm also sharing an image if it.

If anyone can help me with the functional structure and JS. Then I'll put the content inside the tabs.

[Page Link](https://neilpatel.com/blog)

[Screenshot of the part I want to create followed by linking with JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azvph.png)

Thanks In advance!

Comment: this link will help you: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

Comment: Please include your code to understand and solve the issue quicker

Answer (score 0):

**Updated ( 2 )**

**Way One ( With Normal Select )**

**Note:** Make Sure `value` of the `option` and `tab-name` of the `tab` is same

OPTIONS

```
<option>TAB NAME</option> <!--Value returns TAB NAME -->
<option value="tabNam2">TAB NAME TWO</option> <!--Value returns tabNam2-->
```

TABS

```
<div tab-name="TAB NAME" class="tabcontent d-none"></div>    
<div tab-name="tabNam2" class="tabcontent d-none"></div>
```

Try This, Is This What do You Need

```js
function openPage(id){
  const p = document.querySelector("[tab-name='"+id+"']");
  const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs .tabcontent");
  for(var  x =0; x < tabs.length; x++)
      tabs[x].classList.add("d-none");
  if(p !== null){
    p.classList.remove("d-none");
  }
  
  
}
```

```css
.d-none{ display:none; }
```

```html
<select onchange="openPage(this.value)">
  <option value="tabOne">Tab One</option>
  <option value="tabTwo">Tab Two</option>
  <option value="tabThree">Tab Three</option>
</select>

<div class="tabs">
  <div tab-name="tabOne" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Tab One</h3>
    <p>11111111111</p>
  </div>
  
  <div tab-name="tabTwo" class="tabcontent d-none">
    <h3>Tab Two</h3>
    <p>22222222222</p>
  </div>

  <div tab-name="tabThree" class="tabcontent d-none">
    <h3>Tab Three</h3>
    <p>33333333333</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Way Two ( With Styled `a` )**

Custom Dropdown: [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp) help from @MohsenNewtoa

```js
setButtonInnerText(document.querySelector(".dropbtn"))
function openPage(id, a){
  const p = document.querySelector("[tab-name='"+id+"']");
  const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tabs .tabcontent");
  for(var  x =0; x < tabs.length; x++)
      tabs[x].classList.add("d-none");
  if(p !== null){
    document.querySelector(".dropbtn").innerHTML = a.innerHTML;
    p.classList.remove("d-none");
  }  
}

function toggleDrop(drop){
   drop.classList.toggle("d-none");
   drop.onclick = function(e){ drop.classList.add("d-none"); } 
}

function setButtonInnerText(btn){
   const firstOption = btn.parentElement.querySelector("#drop a:first-child");
   btn.innerHTML = firstOption.innerHTML;
}
```

```css
.d-none{ display:none; }

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="toggleDrop(document.querySelector('#drop'))" class="dropbtn"></button>
  <div id="drop" class="dropdown-content d-none">
    <a href="#" onclick="openPage('tabOne', this)">Tab One</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="openPage('tabTwo', this)">Tab Two</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="openPage('tabThree', this)">Tab Three</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tabs">
  <div tab-name="tabOne" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Tab One</h3>
    <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
  </div>

  <div tab-name="tabTwo" class="tabcontent d-none">
    <h3>Tab Two</h3>
    <p>Some news this fine day!</p>
  </div>
  
  <div tab-name="tabThree" class="tabcontent d-none">
    <h3>Tab Three</h3>
    <p>Some news this fine day!</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The styled options seem perfect fit for my work. But on the running code snippet it says "Select". Can you please send me the code where on running code it starts displaying the first option. here in your code, it's "Home".

Comment: I first used a code from codepen where it was using the tab technique. But the problem i faced was with the HTML option tag. The font size couldn't be getting changed on options. I was using a font size of 23px and the dropdown options were looking too big. So the second option you have send seems perfect.

Comment: Now see, I have updated it and now the `innerHTML` of the `button` is taking from the first `a`